# OpenCL OutOfResources

Tags: memory, out-of-memory, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I have an OpenCL Kernel that throws an OutOfResources exception when run.

Note: I am using Cloo for C#

I created a minimum working example of my problem and the kernel now looks like this:

```
__kernel void MinBug
(
    __global float  * img, 
    __global float  * background,
    __global int    * tau   
)
{
    int neighbourhoodSize = tau[0];

    const int x = get_global_id(0); 
    const int y = get_global_id(1);

    for (int i = -neighbourhoodSize; i <= neighbourhoodSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = -neighbourhoodSize; j <= neighbourhoodSize; j++)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

For my original program, this runs fine when tau is small (ie: 2, 10, 15), but once tau gets to be around 27, this sometimes throws an exception. The minimum working example I created does not have this problem until tau gets near 300.

The specific error that I get in my C# program is

> Cloo.OutOfResourcesComputeException: 'OpenCL error code detected:
>   OutOfResources.'

This always happens on the very next line after calling the Kernel.Execute() method.

What concept am I missing?

Comment: I once managed to get this working with tau = 100, nothing seems to have changed, yet my GPU does not like this anymore.

Comment: how do you check out of bounds access to arrays?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I use clipping to do this.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik  here is the clipping code in case you are interested https://pastebin.com/R4TWy3Jb

Comment: Is clip working like `clamp(T x,T min, T max)` but in 2D?

Comment: Actually the minimum working example of this bug does not even need the code inside the loop to cause the exception

Comment: Neighborhood=100 means there are 10k different indices right? How do you check outof bounds ? Can you define clip please?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik yep that's right

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wrRGKf0y

Comment: I can't see how it checks below-zero outof bounds.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik max(0, -1) = 0

Comment: where does 0 come from, where does -1 come from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144041/discussion-between-sav-and-huseyin-tugrul-buyukisik).

Comment: huseyintugrulbuyukisik suggested installing the opencl_runtime and intel sdk for opencl. Since then everything has been working. I can't thank you enough. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Huseyin for his advice on installing the correct runtime.

I also needed to select the correct platform in the code.

On my computer I currently have three platforms.
Two of them seem to be associated with the CPU (intel i7).
And one seems to be the GPU (NVidia gtx 660 ti)

I tried explicitly running on my GPU and it ran out of juice. As you can see from the error message above.

When I specified the CPU

```
CLCalc.InitCL(Cloo.ComputeDeviceTypes.Cpu, 1);
```

It ran much better. Who'd have thought, my CPU seems to have more grunt than the GPU. Maybe its a simplistic metric. Its also worth noting my CPU supports a later version of OpenCL than the GPU.